# Connect ODBC datasource remotely C#.NET

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, odbc

How to enable remote connection to a local ODBC datasource ?

For EG. i have a ms access database in my local machine for which i have created a DSN.

How do i interface the database to outside world using a C# ? I have seen certain applications which allow to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ODBC-ODBC Bridge to access a local MS Access database from a remote machine. Your application uses ODBC on the client to connect to a bridge DSN (which points to the server and dsn on the server) which passes the API calls and data onto a server process running where the db is located.

These bridges can also be quite useful if you have a 32 bit application and a 64 bit driver or vice versa.

I'm not aware of any usable open source bridges but you can get a commercial one from www.easysoft.com.